# Install nginx in Ubuntu17.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I read the [offical documents](https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#distributions),it says,

> For Ubuntu replace codename with Ubuntu distribution codename, and append the following to the end of the /etc/apt/sources.list file:
>
> deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ codename nginx
>   deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ codename nginx

But there is no codename for Ubuntu17.04.
So,my questions are:

1. Should I use codename yakkety for Ubuntu16.10 in my Ubuntu17.04?
2. If not,What codename should I use?

Comment: What do you mean no codename? I see zesty on that page: http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/dists/  And yakkety was 16.10 not 16.04: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames

Comment: I saw here:https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#distributions.

Comment: So,could I think that the page I saw is out of date,and I can use this:deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ zesty nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ zesty nginx

Answer (score 0):

Always use the same codename as the codename of the Ubuntu release that you are using in order to prevent package management conflicts. There are two ways to print the codename in Ubuntu. The first way prints the Ubuntu codename using `lsb_release`, and the second way prints the Ubuntu codename using only bash built-ins. `lsb_release -sc` is easier to use in shell scripts.

#### lsb_release

```
lsb_release -sc
```

#### bash built-ins

```
source /etc/os-release
echo ${UBUNTU_CODENAME}
```

A common use for the Ubuntu codename is in shell scripts to assign it to a variable, so that the same shell script will work on multiple Ubuntu releases.